# Unable to exclude/prune a hidden directory via MANIFEST.in

Tags: python, manifest, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm creating a pip package and it's including `.idea` directories (which exist because I develop using IntelliJ PyCharm) and I don't want these to be packaged.

Therefore, I'm trying to exclude (recursively) these `.idea` directories by using a `MANIFEST.in` file. Here's what my file currently looks like:

```
prune */.idea
prune */__pycache__
global-exclude *.py[co]
```

Regardless of adding `prune */.idea` these directories still appear in the package. I've also tried `recursive-exclude */.idea *` with no luck.

It appears that possibly `MANIFEST.in` has an issue with hidden directories? The reason I believe this is because if I use `prune */test` this works successfully for any recursive `test` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following `MANIFEST.in` syntax works as expected:
`prune **/.idea`